# Как создать запрос по данным учеников?

Tags: sql, reporting-services

Как создать запрос по данным учеников? Пробовал так, но наверно надо как то подругому.

```
SELECT [SSN]
      ,[Studentnumber]
      ,[Surename]
      ,[Forenames]
      ,[Bithdate]
      ,[Address]
      ,[Phonenumber]
FROM [dw].[connected_person_contact_details]
Where (Surename IS NULL OR Surename = @Surename) 
AND (SSN IS NULL OR SSN = @SSN)
AND (Phonenumber IS NULL OR Phonenumber = @Phonenumber)
```

Надо сделать поиск например по одному из выше упомянутых параметров. Или же такой запрос что бы можно было искать по одному или больше параметру.

Comment: а почему вам не нравится текущая реализация ? по моему все логично

Comment: надо не поле, а переменную с `NULL` сранивать, чтобы по заданному параметру искать. `@surname IS NULL` и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [SSN]
      ,[Studentnumber]
      ,[Surename]
      ,[Forenames]
      ,[Bithdate]
      ,[Address]
      ,[Phonenumber]
FROM [dw].[connected_person_contact_details]
Where (@Surename IS NULL OR Surename = @Surename) 
AND (@SSN IS NULL OR SSN = @SSN)
AND (@Phonenumber IS NULL OR Phonenumber = @Phonenumber)
```